# angular6: add universal support with cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-universal

I created a new angular6 application using angular cli and then type :

`ng generate universal`

to add universal support.

I works fine but I wonder why it added

```
"server": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/VulogDeploy-server",
    "main": "ClientApp/main.server.ts",
    "tsConfig": "ClientApp/tsconfig.server.json"
  }
}
```

inside angular.json file. Is there another cli command to generate server app ?

What I try to have a look to the doc I see they are creating a webpack config file and use a webpack command to generate server app.

what is the good way to continue after execution of the `ng generate universal` command ?

Comment: Well you have to host the SSR-app somewhere. You can setup an own node/express-server for this or use a hoster like firebase: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxCu5TEmxXE

Comment: for this part sure, bu I was wondering if I really need a webpack config and generate the code from webpack since I see that cli add a configuration about output. Because of that I'm wondering the purpose of that. Do we have to execute an ng command to build the universal (server side) code instead od the webpack command like in the code ?

Comment: yes, the expected workflow is for you to use webpack to build server.ts which you run in a node server. You should see scripts added in your package.json.

Comment: but why those keys in angular.json ? what is the purpose ?

Comment: these keys are used when building your server-side app.
`ng build --app server`. If I'm not wrong, the webpack uses the generated output to bundle server.ts

Comment: this command is not working. And why to create a webpack config if ng manage it too ?

Comment: sorry, the command doesn't recognize by key but index 0 and 1. The correct command should be `ng build --prod --app 1`. Webpack because there might be configurations that you want to change. Basically they want to give more flexibility to the developers.

Comment: it say Unknown option: '--app'. 
an so it mean I need to choose to use ng OR create a webpack config and use webpack ?

Comment: ok, looking at the code of angular-cli and it seems it works like npm. So there is default command from architectures key that you can run directly (like serve, build, etc) or custom commands that you can start with run.
so correct command seems to be:
`ng run AppName:server`
but still wonder if it's equivalent to webpack config

Comment: My bad, it seems like the latest angular-cli will build client and server bundles with a single ng build command now. ng build --app is only used in previous versions. The underlying of ng serve, ng run is based on webpack, you can even eject the webpack configuration of your angular app using ng eject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you first need to compile the server app using the following command

```
ng run [appName]:server
```

which will create and copy the the server bundle inside the specified folder (`dist/VulogDeploy-server` in your case)

Then, you need to setup the universal webserver with nodejs/express and webpack. You use webpack to compile your `server.ts`, which will use the app bundle created in the first step to do the rendering

The wiki stories have not been updated for angular 6 yet 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering, but I guess the principle remains the same